# Show $\dfrac{2nm}{4n^2+m^2}$ is bounded

Tags: analysis

Show $\dfrac{2nm}{4n^2+m^2}$ is bounded and determine its supremum and infimum, where $n$ and $m$ are natural numbers.  I'm not to sure where to start.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

For upper bound, check two cases $m\le n$ and $m>n$. The infimum is straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

The expression is equivalent to

$$\frac{2q}{q^2+4}$$ where $q$ is a positive rational. We have

$$\frac{2q}{q^2+4}\le\frac q2,$$ and $$\frac{2q}{q^2+4}\le\frac2q$$ so that the expression is bounded.

As the expression is positive and zero for $q=0$, this must be the infimum.

Now the inverse of the expression can be written

$$\frac q2+\frac 2q.$$ This is the sum of a growing and a decreasing term, which achieves an extremum when the terms are equal, i.e. at $q=2$.